# How to get result set of SQL Server stored procedure with parameter in a table or excel?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008, it accepts parameter and outputs a row with 15 columns. I have 100s of parameters to test with.

I do not want to waste time and execute it with each parameter individually and copy the result into an Excel sheet. I want all of them at once.

Can't I run the stored procedure with all the parameters one by one and get all the result in one table?

I have used cursor, I am providing i/ps but same thing, it gives me a separate table for each parameter and that means I have to copy each row one by one

e.g

```
DECLARE @field1 int

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT t.PID 
    FROM dbo.TabletTEST t
    WHERE t.Enumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6..100)

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @field1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC [StoredProcedureToExecute]  @field1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @field1
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table valued function with Cross Apply. Please check msdn doc for Cross Apply example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx